# Javascript: cannot read property value of null

Tags: javascript

I keep receiving the error "cannot read property value of null" in my javascript. Originally the error was occurring when assigning a variable the element value:

```
var breakCal = document.getElementById("breakfast").value;
```

I placed the assignments in conditionals and now I'm receiving the error when trying to change the css property of those elements here:

```
if(passBreakCal == false){ document.getElementById("breakfast").style.borderColor="red"; }
```

does anyone have any suggestions?

```
function verifyDailySum2(){
    if(document.getElementById("breakfast") !== null){
        var breakCal = document.getElementById("breakfast").value;
    }
    else{
        var breakCal = null;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("lunch") !== null) {
        var lunchCal = document.getElementById("lunch").value;
    }
    else{
        var lunchCal = null;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("dinner") !== null) {
        var dinnerCal = document.getElementById("dinner").value;
    }
    else {
        var dinnerCal = null;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("snack") !== null){
        var snackCal = document.getElementById("snack").value;
    }
    else{
        var snackCal = null;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("weight") !== null){
        var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    }
    else{
        var weight = null;
    }

    alert(breakCal + "$" + lunchCal + "$" + dinnerCal + "$" + snackCal + "$" + weight);

    var pattern = /^[0-9]+$/;

    var passBreakCal = pattern.test(breakCal);
    var passLunchCal = pattern.test(lunchCal);
    var passDinnerCal = pattern.test(dinnerCal);
    var passSnackCal = pattern.test(snackCal);
    var passWeight = pattern.test(weight);

    if(passBreakCal == false || passLunchCal == false || passDinnerCal == false ||
        + passSnackCal == false || passWeight == false){
        alert("One of the fields is empty. Or contains characters other than numbers");

        if(passBreakCal == false){
            document.getElementById("breakfast").style.borderColor="red";
        }
        if(passLunchCal == false){
            document.getElementById("lunch").style.borderColor="red";
        }
        if(passDinnerCal == false){
            document.getElementById("dinner").style.borderColor="red";
        }
        if(passSnackCal == false){
            document.getElementById("snack").style.borderColor="red";
        }
        if(passWeight == false){
            document.getElementById("weight").style.borderColor="red";
        }

        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's the php page calling the function. All markup is bootstrap.

```
<?php 
include('session.php');
include('header.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
        <title> Workout Daily Summary </title>
        <link href = "bootstrap-theme.css" rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css"/>
        <link href = "bootstrap.css" rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css"/>
        <link href = "is448_project.css" rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css"/>
        <link href = "bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dailySum.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-sm-4">
    <div class = "border">
    <h3> Daily Summary: </h3>


    <p>
        Please list calories consumed for each meal today:
    </p>

    <form action =  "dailySumTable.php" method="post">

        Breakfast: <input type = "text" name = "breakfast" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/>
        <br/> <br/>
        Lunch:  <input type = "text" name = "lunch" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/>
        <br/> <br/>
        Dinner:  <input type = "text" name = "dinner" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/>
        <br/> <br/>
        Snack:  <input type = "text" name = "snack" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/>
        <br/> <br/>


            Activities Completed Today:<br/>
            <select name = "activity">
                <option value="Running">Running</option>
                <option value="Walking">Walking</option>
                <option value="Weight_Lifting">Weight Lifting</option>
                <option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
                <option value="Biking">Biking</option>
                <option value="Yoga">Yoga</option>
            </select> Time (in minutes): <input type = "text" name = "time1" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/><br/><br/>
            <select name = "activity2">
                <option value="Biking">Biking</option>
                <option value="Running">Running</option>
                <option value="Walking">Walking</option>
                <option value="Weight_Lifting">Weight Lifting</option>
                <option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
                <option value="Yoga">Yoga</option>
            </select> Time (in minutes): <input type = "text" name = "time2" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/><br/><br/>
            <select name = "activity3">
                <option value="Weight_Lifting">Weight Lifting</option>
                <option value="Running">Running</option>
                <option value="Walking">Walking</option>
                <option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
                <option value="Biking">Biking</option>
                <option value="Yoga">Yoga</option>
            </select> Time (in minutes): <input type = "text" name = "time3" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/><br/><br/>
            <select name = "activity4">
                <option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
                <option value="Running">Running</option>
                <option value="Walking">Walking</option>
                <option value="Weight_Lifting">Weight Lifting</option>
                <option value="Biking">Biking</option>
                <option value="Yoga">Yoga</option>
            </select> Time (in minutes): <input type = "text" name = "time4" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/><br/><br/>
            <select name = "activity5">
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                <option value="Swimming">Swimming</option>
                <option value="Running">Running</option>
                <option value="Walking">Walking</option>
                <option value="Weight_Lifting">Weight Lifting</option>
                <option value="Biking">Biking</option>
                <option value="Yoga">Yoga</option>
            </select> Time (in minutes): <input type = "text" name = "time5" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/><br/> <br/>



            Daily Weigh in: <br/> <br/>


        Weight:<input type = "text" name = "weight" size = "4" maxlength = "4"/>
        <br/>



        <input type = "reset" value = "Clear" />
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "return verifyDailySum2()" />

    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-sm-7"> <img class = "curls" src="salad.jpg" alt ="salad"/> </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: link to jsfiddle please or can you add the markup too

Comment: Can you make a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see the error in action

Comment: Have you checked the speling?

Comment: Please do not put spaces around the `=` in HTML. Also you are receiving the error because you do not have an item with an ID of `breakfast`. You will need to add `id="breakfast"` to your `<select>`. Then the javascript will not return null for the `getElementById` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no element with the `id` "breakfast". Only the `name` of the `input` is set to that value.

```html
Breakfast: <input type="text" name="breakfast" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
```

---

Update your element so that it has `id="breakfast"`.

```
<!----------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvv--->
Breakfast: <input type="text" id="breakfast" name="breakfast" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
```

Comment: Updating and checking

Comment: Thanks!! I can't believe I forgot Id's. Thanks for the heads up. I'm still having   an issue with my alert displaying, have any insight there?